# Hide children of the siblings of grand parent in jQuery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I need to hide the children of siblings of the grand parent. I am stuck in complex situation where I have three `<li>` inside the `<ul>` . Now the structure of the html looks like this

```
<ul>
<li>..</li>
<li>..</li>
<li>..</li>
</ul>
```

inside each `li` this is the html

```
      <div class="chbs-vehicle chbs-clear-fix">

         <div class="chbs-vehicle-image chbs-vehicle-image-has-gallery" style="opacity: 1;">
            </div>
            <div class="chbs-vehicle-content">                
                <div class="chbs-vehicle-content-header"> 
                    <span>Sedan</span>                        
            <a href="#" class="chbs-button chbs-button-style-2">
                Select
                <span class="chbs-meta-icon-tick"></span>
            </a>                       
               </div>                   
            <div class="chbs-vehicle-content-price">€42.00</div>                
            </div>
            </div>
```

So when I click on the `chbs-button-style-2` I want to hide `chbs-vehicle-content-price` div inside all the other `li` which are the children of siblings of grandparent of this.

this is I where I am stuck

```
<script type="text/javascript">

jQuery(document).ready(function($){

      $('.chbs-button-style-2').on('click', function() {

       alert($(this).closest('li').siblings().children().find('.chbs-vehicle-content-price').html());
       //Here I am getting Undefined

    });
   });
   
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the [`.hide()`](https://api.jquery.com/hide/) method:

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  $('.chbs-button-style-2').on('click', function() {
    $(this).closest('li').siblings().children().find('.chbs-vehicle-content-price').hide();
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li>
    <div class="chbs-vehicle chbs-clear-fix">

      <div class="chbs-vehicle-image chbs-vehicle-image-has-gallery" style="opacity: 1;">
      </div>
      <div class="chbs-vehicle-content">
        <div class="chbs-vehicle-content-header">
          <span>Sedan</span>
          <a href="#" class="chbs-button chbs-button-style-2">
                Select
                <span class="chbs-meta-icon-tick"></span>
            </a>
        </div>
        <div class="chbs-vehicle-content-price">€42.00</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div class="chbs-vehicle chbs-clear-fix">

      <div class="chbs-vehicle-image chbs-vehicle-image-has-gallery" style="opacity: 1;">
      </div>
      <div class="chbs-vehicle-content">
        <div class="chbs-vehicle-content-header">
          <span>Sedan</span>
          <a href="#" class="chbs-button chbs-button-style-2">
                Select
                <span class="chbs-meta-icon-tick"></span>
            </a>
        </div>
        <div class="chbs-vehicle-content-price">€42.00</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div class="chbs-vehicle chbs-clear-fix">

      <div class="chbs-vehicle-image chbs-vehicle-image-has-gallery" style="opacity: 1;">
      </div>
      <div class="chbs-vehicle-content">
        <div class="chbs-vehicle-content-header">
          <span>Sedan</span>
          <a href="#" class="chbs-button chbs-button-style-2">
                Select
                <span class="chbs-meta-icon-tick"></span>
            </a>
        </div>
        <div class="chbs-vehicle-content-price">€42.00</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>
```